# RecyclerView - Correctly implement SnackBar UNDO deletion (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have successfully implemented the swipe to delete an item from the recyclerView.

When an Item is deleted I want to show a SnackBar with a button that's let's you add back the item if you deleted unintentionally.

I chose to store the swiped item in a variable and delete it.

Then, if the user presses the undo button, it will be added back to the position it used to be.

This is how I did it:

```
override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {

                    val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition //get position which is swipe

                    if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {  //if swipe left
                        val tmp = activeSubs[position] //here I store the temporary Item
                        activeSubs.removeAt(position)
                        adapter!!.removeItem(position)

                        //TODO: translate
                        val layout = find<View>(R.id.active_subs_recycler)
                        Snackbar.make(layout, "Subscription Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Undo", { _ ->
                                    activeSubs.add(position-1, tmp)
                                    adapter!!.notifyItemInserted(position-1)
                                    adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                }).show()
                    }
                }
```

The problem is that when I click the UNDO button, the item isn't added back in the `recyclerView`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like your Adapter's underlying data structure is separate from the one you're adding the item back into.  (This is an assumption made from the need to call removeAt and removeItem in 2 places)

Comment: @submersed Yes you are right I&amp;#39;m keeping a list in the adapter and another in the main_activity. They're the same but I need them both

Comment: @Submersed I answered but somehow the tag didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an adapter method remove item

```
adapter!!.removeItem(position)
```

that is removing the item from the adapter's list and notifying the recycler view.

The undo method however, does not use the adapter list as pointed out by @Submerged, try creating an equivalent method

```
adapter!!.addItem(position)
```

as currently you are adding the item to a different list object, and not the one the adapter uses, so nothing is updated.

P.S call either notifyItemInserted (for an animation )or notifyDataSetChanged (a batch change of data, no animation), not both